# SetCookie with Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to setCookie on a wordpress page load. Unfortunately nothing is happening when I added the script code below. I've been using this code in php `setcookie("gmp_", "1", strtotime( '+30 days' ), '/');` with no problems but now I'm trying to get the Javascript version to work. Am I overlooking something?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
setCookie('gmp_','1',30);    
</script>
```

Comment: That code seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/v1shqpzs/

Comment: where are you running the code from?

Comment: @MichaelColeman i'm running it on a wordpress page.

Comment: hah, ok, how are you trying to inject your javascript into the wordpress system? through a template file, through a child theme?, using a wordpress function? etc

Comment: Is the javascript being loaded into the browser successfully? are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @MichaelColeman I'm adding the script via a page via the Text tab... Do I need a special plugin to run script directly from a page?

Comment: You shouldn't need a plugin. but your first stop should be to check its loading using your browsers developer tools. then how you insert javascript will partly depend on whether you want it to appear on all pages or just the one

Comment: Right after you do `setCookie('gmp_','1',30);`, add this line of code: `console.log("just set cookie");`.  Then, look in the browser debug console and see if you see the message `"just set cookie"`.  That will tell you if your code is even present and being executed.  You can also look in the debug console for any relevant errors being reported on your web page.

Answer (score 2):

Notes the space after ; in split.

```
function ReadCookie()
{
   var allcookies = document.cookie;
   alert("All Cookies : " + allcookies );

   // Get all the cookies pairs in an array
   cookiearray  = allcookies.split('; '); //notes the space after ;

   // Now take key value pair out of this array
   for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++){
       name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
       value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
       alert("Key is : " + name + " and Value is : " + value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is seems to be working fine.... the value of cookie is getting saved in your variable gmp_ with value is equals to 1.

You can check your saved cookie values by the following JS function..

```js
function ReadCookie()
{
   var allcookies = document.cookie;
   alert("All Cookies : " + allcookies );

   // Get all the cookies pairs in an array
   cookiearray  = allcookies.split(';');

   // Now take key value pair out of this array
   for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++){
      name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
      value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
      alert("Key is : " + name + " and Value is : " + value);
   }
}
```